# How to give permission to alter a certain object in a Postgres database without being its owner?

Tags: database, postgresql, roles, privileges

I would like a user in PostgreSQL to have permissions on a certain Database object so that he/she can alter it (e.g. add columns to tables). However, I believe that this is only possible if the user is the owner of the object or if he inherited the permissions from the owner. And that is where the problem lies, because I want that user to have permissions on specific objects because, if I inherit the owner's permissions, he/she will be able to alter objects that I do not want him/her to alter. What do you recommend to do in this situation?

Comment: Create a separate role and make that role owner of tables where you think he/she should have permission to alter.

Comment: can you further explain it. I didn't get the last two sentence. current version quote from manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html: **Superusers can always do this; ordinary roles can only do it if they are both the current owner of the object (or a member of the owning role) and a member of the new owning role.**

Answer (score 0):

Current version (v15) of PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-priv.html) says:

> The right to modify or destroy an object is inherent in being the object's owner, and cannot be granted or revoked in itself. (However, like all privileges, that right can be inherited by members of the owning role; see Section 22.3.)

So only a user that is the owner of a table or is a member of the role that owns the table can alter its structure.
To make a table `my_table` modifiable by several users create a role `owner_of_my_table` and make required users its members.
You'll be able to have as many owner groups as you want so you can make table `A` modifiable by one set of users and table `B` modifiable by another set of users.